# single canvas element calling multiple functions sequentially

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

hi i am new to html5 canvas, i have this doubt please help

suppose there is a single html canvas element in html script

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"/>
```

and i want to display different shapes onto this canvas by invoking separate JSfuntions

eg:
    function draw_circle();
    function draw_square();
    function draw_arc();
.
.
etc

after each shape it draws i want to clear it using

```
context.clearRect(x,y,Width,Height);
```

is it possible this way? or is there an alternative?

Comment: Sure it is! so long as `Width` and `Height` are variables you can access like `var Width = canvas.width;`. With that being said, canvases redraw so fast that you will not be able to see the shapes drawn unless you make it delay in between clearing and redrawing each

Answer (score 0):

It is definetly possible this way, you just need to provide your canvas.width and canvas.height.

If you are looking for an alternative way of drawing circles, arcs, rectangles in a more simple way check out create.js. It has built in functions for drawCircle and other shapes. It also supports a redraw functions for the context.

All the best!